# Using AR in Unity to control a player in game

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore

I am working with Unity3d to create a game and I want to use the AR with the front-facing camera to track when a person moves left then the character in the game would move left (like the kinnect). I know it can be done but I cannot figure out how to link the movement in AR to control the game object movement. Does anyone have any ideas?

By the way this is to do with AR as I need help using the AR foundation in Unity3d!

Comment: Hi there. It seems to me that your question is not concrete enough. You should share the things that you have already tried to make this work, including any relevant research that you have already done.

Comment: I have created the game I want, I also have some code from a developer who has been testing AR where it can detect the body movements and track them. What I need is to tie it together, when tracking someone moving I want the character to move in the same way. Not sure what else I can add to be honest, this is why I am saying I will pay a bit for someone to help...

Comment: Note that the [tag:ar] tag has nothing to do with the AR product or Augmented Reality — it is for the Unix 'ar' program which is used to manage static C libraries.  Tagging this question with the [tag:ar] tag is wrong — don't undo the edit again!